# Issues when replicating from couchbase bucket to elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase

This issue seems to be related to using the XDCR in couchbase. If I had the following simple objects

```
1: { "name" : "Mark", "age" : 30}
2: { "name" : "Bill", "age" : "forty"}
```

and set up an elasticsearch index as such

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/couchbaseDocument/_mapping' -d '
  {
    "couchbaseDocument" : {
      "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "store_generic": {
          "match": "*",
          "mapping": {
            "store": "yes"
          }
        }
      }
      ]
    }
}'
```

I can then add the two objects to this index using the REST API

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/couchbaseDocument/1 -d '{
  "name" : "Mark",
  "age" : 30
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/couchbaseDocument/2 -d '{
  "name" : "Bill",
  "age" : "forty"
}'
```

They are now both searchable (despite the fact the "age" is `long` for one and `string` for the other.

If, however, I stored these two objects in a couchbase bucket (rather than straight to elasticsearch) and set up the XDCR the first object replicates fine but the second fails with the following error

> failed to execute bulk item (index) index {[test][couchbaseDocument][2], source[{"doc":{"name":"Bill","age":"forty"},"meta":{"id":"2","rev":"8-00000b9360d0a0bf0000000000000000","expiration":0,"flags":0}}]}
>   org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse [doc.age]

I can't figure out why it works via the REST API but not when couchbase replicates the same objects.

I followed the answer and used the following mapping to get things to work via XDCR

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/couchbaseDocument/_mapping' -d '
{
    "couchbaseDocument" : {
      "properties" : {
        "doc": {
          "properties" : {
            "name" : {"type" : "string", "store" : "yes"},
            "age" : {"type" : "string", "store" : "yes"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
}'
```

Now all the objects (despite having different types for the same fields) are replicated and searchable. I don't think there was any need to include the `dynamic_templates` approach I initially tried. The mapping works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's something you have to solve on elasticsearch side.

If the same field name can contain both numeric values and string values, you should create a mapping first which says that `age` is a String.
So elasticsearch won't try to auto guess type for this field.

Hope this helps

Comment: What would I do in the situation where the `age` field is not introduced until after the mapping has been defined so it is first introduced as a number, the mapping is updated, but then it occurs as a string? In this scenario I can't specify it to be treated as a string in the initial mapping because I don't know it is even going to occur as a property. Does this make sense?

Comment: It will fail. First doc having that field will give the type. And you can not change a type. May be using template you can say that all fields should be treated as Strings.